# How to Install phpMyAdmin on Amazon Linux running nginx

Tags: mysql, linux, nginx, amazon-ec2, phpmyadmin

I have not been able to successfully install and configure `phpMyadmin` on `Amazon Linux` running `nginx`.

Here are the commands I run:

```
# Configure repel to install phpMyadmin
sudo yum-config-manager --enable epel

# Install phyMyAdmin
sudo yum install phpmyadmin -y

# Create a symbolic link to phpMyadmin
sudo ln -s /usr/share/phpMyAdmin /var/www/html/phpmyadmin
```

When I try to go to the installation `mydomain.com/phpmyadmin` I get a `404 error`

My nginx.conf

```
server {
   listen 80;
   server_name  server_name www.domain.com domain.com;

   location / {
       root   /var/www/html;
       index  index.php index.html index.htm;
   }

   location ~ \.php$ {
       root /var/www/html;
       fastcgi_pass   unix:/var/run/php-fpm/php-fpm.sock;
       fastcgi_index  index.php;
       fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include        fastcgi_params;
    }
}
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: I Guess ask Amazon for assistance? If you bought servers by them, they should help you at the start.

Comment: @MartinJoneš that is no help

Comment: Could you paste your nginx config?

Comment: @CV-Gate I just pasted it

Comment: I think that you are making the symlink to `phpmyadmin` and configuring `html` as root into the nginx config file

Comment: @CV-Gate so what should my nginx.conf file look like?

Comment: Maybe changing this line `root   /var/www/html;` to `root   /var/www/html/phpmyadmin;`

Comment: @CV-Gate that did not work

Comment: I think this was part of the problem, another point could be the php configuration, do you have any other php script working in this server? Also, excuse me for the stupid question, did you restart nginx?

Comment: @CV-Gate So `sudo ln -s /usr/share/phpMyAdmin /var/www/html/phpmyadmin` is what it should have been I did not have the capital M and A. It is now working without changing the nginx.conf file. Thanks

Comment: Great, happy you got it

Answer (score 0):

So the following worked for me

```
sudo ln -s /usr/share/phpMyAdmin /var/www/html/phpmyadmin
```

and this

```
sudo chmod 777 /var/lib/php/session
```